# java sending UTF-16 data to PHP not working

Tags: java, php, json, character-encoding, utf-16

I'm sending data to php from java using JSON, using following code:

```
String url = "abc.php";

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("msg", message); // message: "\ud83d\udc4d \ud83d\udc4e"

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 100000);

HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

StringEntity se = new StringEntity("json="+json.toString());
post.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
post.setEntity(se);

HttpResponse response;
response = client.execute(post);
String resFromServer = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

Log.i("resFromServer", resFromServer);
```

The PHP code is:

```
if( isset($_POST["json"]) ) {

    $jsonDecode = json_decode($_POST["json"]);

    $msg = $jsonDecode->{"msg"};

    echo $msg;
}
```

But I'm getting output as **????**

Whereas output should be

Is there some encoding issue? How can this be fixed?

Comment: I think you need to use PHP `mb_convert_encoding()` or send with `utf-8` from Java instead of `utf-16`. Convert it before decoding the json.

Comment: @frz3993 please can you tell how?

Comment: Try `$input = mb_convert_encoding($_POST["json"], "UTF-8", "UTF-16");`. Then `$jsonDecode = json_decode($input);` and continue with your code.

Comment: @frz3993 I'm getting error from php as "Trying to get property of non-object". How to get $msg in this case?

Comment: Try, `echo mb_detect_encoding($_POST['json']);` first to make sure you really receive utf-16 on your PHP side.

Comment: @frz3993 got output from that as ASCII

Comment: @frz3993 tried $input = mb_convert_encoding($_POST["json"], 'UTF-16', 'ASCII'); But doesn't work

Comment: If it's ASCII, it is supposed to be `$input = mb_convert_encoding($_POST["json"], 'UTF-16', 'ASCII');`.

Comment: @frz3993 I tried that and I mentioned it in above comment, but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try , first converting the requested content to utf8
Those strings might not be UTF-16 actually. So do it safe and try

```
if( isset($_POST["json"]) ) {
    $string=$_POST['json'];
    $jsonDecode = mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8", mb_detect_encoding($string));
    $jsonDecode = json_decode($jsonDecode);

    $msg = $jsonDecode->{"msg"};

    echo $msg;
}
```

Comment: @RohitKumar, I think `utf8_encode()` is to convert from IS0-8859-1 to utf-8

Comment: @RohitKumar getting error as "Trying to get property of non-object". How to get $msg in this case?

Comment: seems to do more research over this , being unknown to java ,let me try again

Comment: @RohitKumar var_dump of first $jsonDecode is giving ""{sm"g":????}"" when using mb_convert_encoding($_POST["json"], 'UTF-16', 'UCS-2LE'); This is pretty close. Can you tell some other encoding other than UCS-2LE?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90774/discussion-between-rohit-kumar-and-user5155835).